# Will a lock be persisted when control flows to a lambda function outside that lock?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, locking

Suppose I have the following code:

```
void DoStuff( SomeClass withObject )
{
    Action helper = () =>
    {
        withObject.RunHelper();
    }
    lock( withObject ) {
       actuallyDoStuff( helper );
    }
}

void actuallyDoStuff( Action action )
{
    action();
}
```

you see, the `Action helper` code is outside the `lock`. I'd expect that `Action` is just an unnamed function so calling it would not get control outside the `lock` and the `lock` would persists.

Yet I'm not sure.

Will the `lock` be released or persisted while control is inside `Action helper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will.

This will happed because standart control flow will be blocked on the `actuallyDoStuff` method exetucion, until the end of that exetucion. That delegate that you pass as the parameter is nothing then just pure MSIL code which is injected (or not, I don't really know, but acts like) into that method and run successefully inside the `lock` scope.

So, the lock will persist because there is no "outside".

Answer (score 3):

The `lock` will continue to be held.

There's no code "outside the lock" here; what matters isn't where the code is written or what it looks like (even lambda functions are in the end class methods, there's absolutely no difference), but only from where it's *called*. Since you are calling it while holding the lock there's nothing more to say about it.